# Can i rewrite InputMethodService in Android?

Tags: java, android, url-rewriting

I'm developing a keyboard on Android.

I have an issue when deleting `ExtractEditText` in `FullScreen` mode.
There are two ways I can do it:

1) I can call 
`KeyboardView.parent().parent().child().setVisibility(View.GONE);`

2) Maybe I can rewrite `InputMethodService` and do `ExtractEditText` and make it permanently `GONE`.

The problem is:

- Can I copy\paste system `InputMethodService` code and rewrite it, or would that have bad effects?
- Can I use the bug\feature, described in item (1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service is part of the compiled Android platform, so you can't just edit it like that.

Comment: Oh, thanks, and cant i just delete this system view?

Comment: Like you are in item 1?  I guess that might work.. though it's a bit brittle as future versions of Android might change the layout..  that may, or may not, be a concern for you though.